# Возможно ли с помощью css+html сделать двух-цветные буквы шрифта?

Tags: html, css, шрифты, color

Необходимо сделать на странице двух- (а, возможно, потом и трёх-) цветные буквы, по такому принципу:

[image: Двухцветная буква]

Букв будет много и разных цветов, не хочется использовать изображения.
Пожалуйста, подскажите, возможно ли это сделать средствами CSS и HTML (ну ещё может JavaScript как-то помочь, если первых недостаточно)?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23569441/1548895

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Еще как вариант

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  width:  50px;
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
h1:before,
h1:after{
    content: 'A';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    color: red;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gradient-3:before,
.gradient-3:after{
    width: 33.333%;
}
.gradient-3:after{    
    left: 50%;
    color: green;       
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;        
    text-indent: -33.333%;
}
/* hack for ff */
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .gradient-3:after {
     text-indent: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>A</h1>
<h1 class="gradient-3">A</h1>
```

Comment: Благодарю, как раз только что обнаружил что предыдущий вариант некорректно отображается в некоторых браузерах (opera mini), а этот, пусть и не такой симпатичный, работает, похоже, везде.

Answer (score 14):

Так?

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  width:  50px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red 49%, blue 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>A</h1>
```

**UPD:** Добавил вертикальное деление. Не самое идеальное решение, может кто-то предложит и получше.

**UPD2:** Оставлю и горизонтальный вариант, мало ли кому пригодится.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 49%, blue 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>A</h1>
```

**UPD3:** Код для 3 цветов

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  width:  50px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red 30%, green 30%, green 60%, blue 60%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>A</h1>
```

Comment: Отилично, очень признателен, то что надо. Только вот ещё один вопрос - а трёх-цветный градиент таким образом возможно сделать? Попробовал три цвета по 33% указать - отображаются только два.

Comment: @federk: если Вам градиент нужен, смотрите, [**как я реализовал**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/blob/master/themes/sashapelican/static/css/sections/sublime-text.css#L22-L34) его у себя на сайте. [**Демонстрация**](http://i.imgur.com/idnvzA2.png). Там по ссылке есть, как с несколькими цветами делать градиент. Спасибо.

Comment: @federk Пример трехцветного градиента [вот](https://jsfiddle.net/daniel217/p1r80mf4/1/), а генерировать градиент можно на сайтах типо [этого](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'\-moz\-linear\-gradient\%28left\%2C\%20rgba\%28255\%2C38\%2C0\%2C1\%29\%200\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28255\%2C30\%2C0\%2C1\%29\%2031\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%280\%2C0\%2C255\%2C1\%29\%2032\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%280\%2C0\%2C255\%2C1\%29\%2066\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%280\%2C255\%2C0\%2C1\%29\%2067\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%280\%2C255\%2C0\%2C1\%29\%20100\%25\%29\%3B')

Comment: Добавил в ответ 3-ех цветный градиент

Comment: @erm А почему используется нестандартное свойство `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` вместо стандартного `color: transparent`?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, чтобы не webkit'ы всё-таки показали непрозрачный текст. Впрочем, правильнее было бы использовать `@supports`.

Answer (score 8):

С псевдоэлементами, и дублированием текста в атрибут можно реализовать и не только для отдельных букв.

Суть метода в том, чтобы клонировать текст в псевдоэлементы через `content: attr(data-text)`, сам текст сделать прозрачным и отобразить только текст из `:before` и `:after`. А дальше остается только разнести их в разные части блока и выставить отрицательный `z-index`, чтобы текст можно было нормально выделить.

```css
p[data-text] {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p[data-text]:before,
p[data-text]:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-text);
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #000;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

p[data-text]:before {
  line-height: 0;
}

p[data-text]:after {
  top: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p data-text="Doublecolor text">Doublecolor text</p>
```

Comment: По вертикали так не выйдет.

Answer (score 6):

Для кроссбразурной работы и без возни с абсолютно позиционированными элементами используйте SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150" width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="52%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);" />
      <stop offset="52%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text x="0" y="150" textLength="150" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" font-family="Arial Black, Arial" font-size="200" fill="url(#gradient)">
    A
  </text>
</svg>
```

Тут в принципе несложно, просто игра с отступами градиентов.